# Create sql trigger with sum and multiple table joins that will update multiple records

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm new at posting but have learned much from browsing in the past. I can't seem to find a solution for this issue.

I'm creating a trigger to update a column with the sum of another table after an Update or Delete. To complicate the matter I have to determine which column to update (Metric1,Metric2,...Metric5) based upon another column that references a look-up table to map the value to one of the 5 metric columns. The logic works perfectly as long as the update affects only one record.

If I perform an update of multiple records I get this error

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Here is the code:

ALTER TRIGGER[dbo].[UpdateMetric_UPD] ON [dbo].[JobMat]

AFTER UPDATE,DELETE

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

```
BEGIN
```

Update JobPhases

```
     Set Metric1=(Select Sum(INS.Qty) 

     FROM (((INSERTED INS

      JOIN JobMat JM

     ON JM.JobCode=INS.JobCode And JM.JSFXDetail=INS.JSFXDetail)

       JOIN Inventory Inv

      ON Inv.PartNum=JM.Code)    

      JOIN MatGroupMap MGM

      ON MGM.[GroupNum]=Inv.MetricGroup )

      WHERE MGM.GroupMap=1

      GROUP BY

      INS.JobCode,INS.JsfxDetail,INS.Code,MGM.GroupMap

      )  

    Where JobPhases.JobCode IN (SELECT JobCode From Inserted)  

    And JobPhases.JSFXDetail IN (SELECT JSFXDetail From INSERTED)
```

End

End

Comment: You ought to be storing the same "type" of data in a single column, and only look to *pivot* the data at the output stage. Storing *computed* data is (usually) best avoided or, in the alternative, done by using indexed views that are *already* implemented to store and update these values automatically.

Comment: PS - this code only updates for Metric1, I would have 5 instances of this update statement after i get it working.

Comment: Damien - if i were only storing in a single column, i think I'd still have this issue - would I not?

Comment: Difficult to tell. You've convoluted the problem without telling us what the actual data structures (simplified) look like nor what your updates are performing nor the expected final result. I can only comment on the overall goal at this point.

Comment: The table JobPhases contain information about a project. The users may configure different "metrics" that they want to monitor. If the user chooses to select a metric based upon the quantity of a material type charged to the project (JobMat), the JobPhases table is to have that metric value set to the total quantity of material. A query is later passed to a crystal report where the metric is used along with labor hours to provide the user with a qty per hour etc.

Comment: This looks an implementation of EAV. Regardless your trigger logic is majorly flawed. You are not handling your data as a set here. A trigger fires once per operation, not once per row. If you have a multiple row insert or delete your code is going to update things in ways you don't want to happen. You need to be joining JobPhases to inserted. There just seems to be a breakdown in understanding the data here.